# How can i open the link in browser outside the app in ionic framework without using inappbrowser plugin?

Tags: ionic-framework

cordova Barcode Scanner plugin in ionic framework for scanning Qrcodes.i want to open the Qrcode in android web browser without using inappbrowser plugin that is link is open outside my app i mean its not a part of my app.so can it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `window.open(theWebAddress)`

Comment: i have used window.open or $window.location but both opened in system browser.i want to open in browser which is not a part of my app without using inappbrowser.

Comment: Why would you not use InAppBrowser? It is exactly for what you are trying to do

Comment: i am using with LaunchMyApp plugin which is launch my app using mobile web browser first time when i click on button it check my app and launch it and scan the qrcode and redirect again to the web browser but in second attempt it crash the app because it is already in app and enable to launch the app thats the problem.thats way i want to open the url outside my app.

Comment: The InAppBrowser **plugin** can do it for you: `window.open("http://google.com", "_system")` opens the website in the device's browser, not in the app itself.

Comment: ok thanks its working but the problem is every time it open new tab is there any solution it open the same tab like parent tab?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following code in the $ionicPlatform.ready function.

document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

This will register a new event and when you open again the app resume event will be fired.

Happy Coding :)

Sarim Ghani